# Match zero or more occurrence of string Regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match some pattern, reference this [online tool](https://pythex.org/) for easy test

```
pattern = r"(^/\w+)\s*?(\w+)"
string_1 = "/path_one path_two"
string_2 = "/path_one_only"
```

While string_1 matches as expected by returning both parts, for string_2 it cuts the last character of part one. But I would like the pattern to always return both parts, rather return None/empty string if path two does not exist

Comment: `+` means *one* or more. So in order to the regex to match, it has to capture at least one char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this pattern:

```
pattern = r"(^/\w+)\s*(\w*)"
```

Now the second string will match entirely in the first capture group.

The reason the final character was being clipped in the second string can be seen here:

```
(^/\w+)  - matches 'path_one_onl'
\s*?     - matches nothing (there are no spaces)
(\w+)    - matches 'y'
```

In other words, the second capture group was imposing that at least one character be matched there.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Comment: @Paullo Glad to help you :-)

Answer (score 1):

Change your pattern string to

1. either

   ```
   pattern = r"(^/\w+)\s*(\w+)?"
   ```
2. or

   ```
   pattern = r"(^/\w+)\s*(\w*)"
   ```

You do not need `\s*?`, just `\s*` is fine.

Comment: Thanks @hjpotter, both answers are correct. Am accepting Tim's answers because it came first and has added more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make the whole second part (spaces included) optional by adding a non capturing group around it:

```
r"(^/\w+)(?:\s+(\w+))?"
```